# including a negative number in the log sum of exponents, in python

Tags: python, numpy, sum, exp

I want to use numpy's `logsumexp()` in python 2.7.
The formula I need to solve looks like this:

```
log ( 1 + e^a1 + e^a2 + e^a3 + ... e^an - e^ax )
```

The last term which is a negative number just has to be appended on.
Excluding this last term, I would do the following:

```
myarray = numpy.array([0, a1, a2, a3, ..., an])
```

That way, with the first element being `0`, then `e^0 = 1` and so I have my first term, which is `1`. Then I would just use

```
  result = numpy.logsumexp(myarray)
```

and I would get the correct result.

But now I have to append a `-e^ax`, and because it's negative, I can't simply append `ax` to the end of `myarray`. I also can't append `-ax` because that's just wrong, it would mean that I'm adding `1/e^ax`, instead of `-e^ax`.

Is there any direct way to append this so that I can still use `logsumexp()`? The only reason I'm insisting on using `logsumexp()` rather than separately using `numpy.exp()` and `numpy.sum()` and `numpy.log()` is because I have the impression that `logsumexp` also incorporates stability within it in order to prevent underflows (correct me if I'm wrong). However if there's no other way around then I guess I have no choice.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `scipy.misc.logsumexp` from SciPy 0.12?

Comment: yes I can use scipy, I have 0.13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to `scipy.misc.logsumexp` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html):

> ```
> scipy.misc.logsumexp(a, axis=None, b=None)
>
> Parameters:   
>     b: array-like, optional
>         Scaling factor for exp(a).
>         Must be of the same shape as a or broadcastable to a.
>     New in version 0.12.0.
> ```

So, you could add list of factors like this:

```
In [2]: a = [0, 1, 3, 2]

In [3]: logsumexp(a, b=[1] * (len(a) - 1) + [-1])
Out[3]: 2.7981810916785101
```

Comment: Thanks - but I don't exactly understand how to use it for my case? I need to subtract e^ax from the list. I tried to follow what you wrote using a calculator but got a different answer, or I guess my python isn't good enough to follow.

Comment: Hmm... Line #23 should do the trick. Could you, please, add an example, producing unexpected result?

Comment: Alright, example: I need to take the log of the sum of `e^0 + e^1 + e^3 - e^2`. So the sum is about `16.41476`. Then the log of this is about `2.79818...`. So the final result should be `2.79818`. (Not rounded exactly).

Comment: I've updated the post with your example, does it solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you! Yes this works. Could you please explain though? I understand that `b` equals to 1 * the last element of `a`, but why the `+[-1]` ?

Comment: No, expression `[1] * (len(a) - 1) + [-1]` generates list with all `1` except last, which is `-1`. Just input this in python.

Comment: Would you happen to know this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651480/does-scipy-logsumexp-deal-with-the-underflow-challenge