# Does scipy logsumexp() deal with the underflow challenge?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, natural-logarithm

Does the scipy's `logsumexp()`  implementation include the hack that prevents underflow by subtracting the maximum found value in the array from each element?

The one explained here below, where `m = maxval`:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call this a hack. Unless floating point numbers are also a hack.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inspect the source code defining `logsumexp` [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/misc/common.py#L18). (Note that there is a link to the source on [the doc page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html)).

You'll see:

```
a_max = a.max(axis=0)
...
out = log(sum(exp(a - a_max), axis=0))
```

So yes, scipy's `logsumexp` is subtracting the maximum from each element.